Does this video show Israeli settlers seizing a house during the funeral of Shireen Abu Akleh?
In 2022, after the killing of Palestinian-American journalist, Shireen Abu Akleh, Al-Jazeera Arabic (@AJArabic) posted this video on X (Twitter).
The video shows a large number of Israeli Jews hurriedly unloading a bus full of bedding and other belongings.
AJArabic claims they were Israeli settlers "seizing a building belonging to the Al-Ja'bari family in Hebron" as taking advantage of the "Palestinian street's preoccupation with the funeral of Shireen Abu Akleh" (by Google translate).
Does the video show Israelis seizing a house?

I was unable to glean through context who "the Al-Ja'bari family" were; it seems a common name. Is it a family related to Shireen Abu Akleh? Is it family well-known to the AJ Arabic readers? Is it just a random Palestinian family?

It'a a Palestinian family, not related to related to Shireen Abu Akleh, and yes it's well-known to the Palestinian Arabic readers as Palestinians usually refer to individuals by their root family.

Clearly it doesn't. It just shows people getting off a bus. Where they are going is out of the frame. What's the point of a Q like this?

@Believeitornot...: The Q is about Al-Jazeera's claim on the related video. Obviously.

So, is your Q if a house was seized in the circumstances alleged (in which case some text article would be preferable, as it would have more details), or just if the video shows that?

The former as well as whether the people, who were shown in the video moving the belongings, were moving it while in the process of seizing the house.

Note that al Jabari is the name of a tribe, so their members have a lot of houses in the area https://www.un.org/unispal/document/auto-insert-196200/ https://english.wafa.ps/Pages/Details/133401 Given the 2022 date, it's probably referring to this one https://www.aljazeera.com/features/2022/4/26/microcosm-palestinian-struggle-one-familys-life-hebron

See also this webpage: https://www.jewishvoiceforlabour.org.uk/article/jewish-settlers-stole-my-house-its-not-my-fault-theyre-jewish/

No.
This video shows Israeli settlers entering a house they bought in Hebron on the same day as the funeral of Shireen Abu Akleh.
This is The Tkuma (Revival) House in Hebron, which was sold by the Al-Jabari family, through a straw man to the Harchivi fund, their FB post with videos.
Al-Jabari family issues a statement regarding the house taken over by settlers in Hebron, by Ramallah News (translated by Google):

The statement said: "The property was leaked to the settlers by the so-called Abu Ali Harhash, a resident of Jerusalem, after he bought the house for 500,000 Jordanian dinars, from Muhammad Eid al-Jabari, a resident of Jerusalem."

The house was evacuated after a few days (Translated from Hebrew):

The "Harhivi" fund, which purchased the Takuma House in Hebron, reached an agreement with the security forces on Sunday evening, according to which the building will be occupied only after the approvals [are finalized], and in the meantime a permanent military presence will remain there.


According to the directors of the fund, when the Arabs learned that Jews had purchased the house, they intended to invade it and hold it. The rapid action of the Jews last weekend prevented an Arab invasion [to the house] and helped establish a permanent military force at home.

In June of 2024 they returned to the house permanently after the approval was finalized (Translated from Hebrew):

Today!! For the second time!! And this time for good!!
Returning home! To the Tkuma house!!
With great excitement!
The Tkuma House received approval from the Civil Administration today.

And finally, about the supposed reason to chose the time of the move because of "Palestinian street's preoccupation with the funeral of Shireen Abu Akleh". Israeli settlements are not evacuated by Palestinians, they are evacuated by the Israeli military, exactly as was in this case. So the preoccupation of the Palestinians is irrelevant, if they wanted to fly under someone's radar, it would be the Israeli authorities' and not the Palestinians'.

I don't know which narration is correct but I've seen many videos (e.g. this one) and I have read many articles that there is some form of government support for settlers to occupy Palestinian lands and homes. These facts strengthen the claim of Al Jazeera mentioned in the question. isn't?

@C.F.G, the Harhivi fund bought that house and a Palestinian news source quotes the previous owners admit that they sold the house. This is a clear case with no disputes. The video you show in the comment is from a different time and place and have no relation to this specific case. More over, the video you show is supposedly from Sheikh Jarrah which is an entirely different issue.
